# Remove loop numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to simulate inventory levels over many days, where the buying behaviour depends on several factors. The main problem is that the code is build upon loops, which are very slow for the amount of data and days. The initial data looks like:

```
Vendor Article_ID Inventory Bought Incoming
1      1000       55        10     30
2      2000       33        10     23
2      2001       22        33     0
```

Code is like:

```
Loop over the number of days
    Loop over the vendor
         Loop over the articles
```

The main problem is the innermost loop. I update the inventory for each iteration

```
for i in Articles:    
#Mask for the article and date today
B = np.where((df[:,0] == dat) & (df[:,4] == i[4]))
#Mask for the article and date yesterday
C = np.where((df[:,0] == Yest) & (df[:,4] == i[4]))

Inventory = df[C,6].item()
Incoming = df[C,17].item()
Bought = df[C,20].item()

#Update for this article. And continue with the next one
df[B,6] = Inventory + Incoming -  Bought
```

Is it possible to vectorize this somehow? Maybe by doing a mask for all the articles and calculate them without looping trough all articles? Example:

```
# All articles:
 Articles = [1000,2000,2001]
 #Mask for the article and date today
 B = np.where((df[:,0] == dat) & (df[:,4] == Articles))
 C = np.where((df[:,0] == Yesterday) & (df[:,4] == Articles))
 Inventory = df[B,6]
 Incoming = df[B,17]
 Bought = df[C,20]

df[B,6] = Inventory + Incoming -  Bought
```

EDIT2: Im thinking about something like this. But how can I be sure that the isin() returns the result in the same order so that I do the calculations with the correct values for that article?

```
#df[:,0] date column. df[:,4] ArticleID (Not dataframe)

B = np.where((df[:,0] == dat) & (np.isin(df[:,4],[2000,2001])))
C = np.where((df[:,0] == Yest) & (np.isin(df[:,4],[2000,2001])))

Inventory = df[B,6]
Bought = df[C,8]

Something = Inventory - Bought
```

EDIT: There are 1600 products in total, and i would love to reach ~200 days.

Comment: "I want to simulate inventory levels over many days, where the buying behaviour depends on several factors." How are days represented in your data?

Comment: I actually start by multiplying each article with as many days i would like to simulate. So in the example above, the number of likes in the array will be articles * days.